# Php's set_time_limit throws a 500 error?

Tags: php

When I use `set_time_limit` and the script runs for any amount of time greater than 360 seconds, it throws a 500 error.

359, nothing, 360 and above, error.

I don't have access to php.ini, how can I fix this bug?

Comment: I had the same error once. The problem was not in the php.ini file but in the PHP script I wrote. The thing may be that you have set `error_reporting` to `off` so you can't see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> script runs for any amount of time greater than 360 seconds, it throws a 500 error.

It sounds like you're hitting another timeout somewhere.  If your server uses FastCGI, for example, Apache and/or the FastCGI process could be configured to only wait for six minutes (360 seconds) before timing out.  It also could be that there's a reverse proxy sitting between you and Apache with the same timeout, though proxy timeouts are usually 504s, not 500s.

Please examine your server configuration.  If you're on shared hosting, ask your host about the timeout.

If your script needs to execute for an extended time, you may wish to find another way to run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache you can change maximum execution time by .htaccess with this line

`php_value max_execution_time 200`