# php Set_time_limit for a long running script

Tags: php

I have a php script that will surely take very long time to process. Is it good to have it in set_time_limit(0); I have seen some times even when we set time limit to 0 we get 500 internal server error. What is best way to handle such long time consuming script in php?

Comment: set_time_limit(0); is a better option , i have been using it to execute very large amt of data and its working fine...

Comment: Just keep in mind when you set_time_limit, the timer gets reset. so if you are iterating through an array, set some appropriate time in the foreach loop. this will prevent the process taking years but still gives enough time to execute the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to execute a long running script from the browser, you have a chance of running into all sorts of timeouts, from php, proxies, web servers and browsers. You may not be able to control all of them.

Any long running script should be run from the command line. That way you take out all of the problems except for the php execution time limit which is easy to override.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to php.ini file then set max_execution_time in it like

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

or you can user .htaccess to handle it like

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451503/phps-set-time-limit-throws-a-500-error

Answer (score -1):

Script which runs more than 360 seconds(I hope `max_execution_time`) will throw an Internal server error automatically even `set_time_limit` is applied.

You can have this in your page.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_input_time', time in seconds);
ini_set('max_execution_time', time in seconds);
?>
```

or in php.ini

set `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` whatever you like.

or in .htaccess

```
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```